# How do I place my Hamburger Menu icon on the right side of my Title?

Tags: html, css

How do I place my hamburger menu icon on the right side of my Webpage name? So it would look like this: (Hamburger Icon) Tools

The image below shows the word "Tool" overlaps with the Hamburger icon. I want them side by side. I've tried placing the hamburger and the word into separate container but it didn't came out right.

Below the images, are my current codes.

**Current Navbar**

[image: Navbar]

**Wanted Navbar**

[image: navbar]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.my-row {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}

.my-col {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #bb0008;
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <!--Hamburger Menu-->
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>

    <ul class="menu__box">
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <h1>Tools</h1>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flexbox`. See the example below just a basic example.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: brown;
}

.hamburger {
  border: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: grid;
  background: none;
  place-items: center;
}

.hamburger svg {
  fill: white;
}

ul {
  display: none;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button class="hamburger">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
      <path d="M4 6h16v2H4zm0 5h16v2H4zm0 5h16v2H4z"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1> Tools </h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the hamburger icon still overlaps with the h1 word

Comment: oh sorry! I forgot to add `h1`

Comment: Same as what I mention to another answer below. I want the Hamburger and the word to be side by side. Not for both of them to be on either side of the nav bar.

Comment: see the updated code

Comment: thanks, its perfectly what I wanted. But can I ask was the button suppose to be able to be pressed?

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I integrate with my current code, I'm just curious if the button was supposed to be able to be pressed

Comment: You made hamburger icon using `checkbox`. I just put `svg` for visuals for telling how its done. Apart that yes of course you can create interactive hamburger icon using `button`

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
}

.my-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.my-row {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}

.my-col {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #bb0008;
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn > span,
.menu__btn > span::before,
.menu__btn > span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.menu__btn > span::before {
  content: "";
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn > span::after {
  content: "";
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #cfd8dc;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-brand {
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
      <!--Hamburger Menu-->
      <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
          <span></span>
        </label>
        <ul class="menu__box">
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <h1 class="nav-brand" >Tools</h1>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't change anything

Comment: Kindly check the output, It's working

Comment: No, I think you have misunderstood my question. I want to place the hamburger icon on the right side of my H1 tag "Tools". I didn't meant it to have both on each end of the navbar. So the icon and the word is side by side.

Comment: updated my answer. kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

It isnt the best practice, but an easy fix in this case could be to add the following to the stylesheet for the menu button:

```
margin-left: 95%;
```

this is better than using a pixel specific margin as it will be relative to the screen (keep this in mind for the other parts of the style sheet when considering cross compatibility as px amounts stay the same across all devices, whereas if you use % instead, it's relative to screen size)

Adding the left margin has the following result:
[image: edited_example]

like I said it's obviously not the best way to do this, making some use of parent containers or a grid layout or something similar would be more acceptable, but this line in the stylesheet should suffice for a quick easy fix

could be worth looking at the following on w3 schools if you aren't familiar with css layouts:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_website_layout.asp

Could also be worth looking at the following on responsive web design if you aren't already familiar with it:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

EDIT:

I now realise I didnt really answer the question you were asking, however I think your best way forward is to look at wrapping everything in parent div's and using those to style your elements accordingly.

I also think you should try making use of  tags rather than the , and use an  tag within the  tag to add your icons. There is a tutorial on this which you can find below @ W3 Schools
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_navbar_icon.asp

Comment: Please read what I've commented on other answer. I want to place the icon beside the word not for both of them to be on either side of the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Icon to position relative, it is relative to other objects.
Afaik you can't do this with position: fixed.

You also need to change the display property to inline-block on both (or else they are block mode and take the complete row)

Because your menu-box is position fixed, it will be on top of the button, you will need another button to close or make the box smaller (height - the top bar)

```css
h1, .hamburger-menu{ display: inline-block; }

.hamburger-menu{ width: 32px; position: relative; }


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.my-row {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}

.my-col {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #bb0008;
}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  /*position: fixed; this needs to leave*/
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <h1>Tools</h1>
  <!--Hamburger Menu-->
  <div class="hamburger-menu">
    <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
      <span></span>
    </label>

    <ul class="menu__box">
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the positioning, but it kind of broke my function. The hamburger and word is side by side now but is in a weird position, one is up, while the other is down. My hamburger menu can't close anymore with the updates css.